# File is not downloading and progress is not showing properly in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-external-storage

I Write a code to download a file with circle progress bar. But file is not downloading into external storage and progress bar does not display any progress number. No error is shown in logcat. I don't no what is wrong in my code. Help me to solve this problem. Here is my code. I have added all the permission and activity classes in manifest file. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.skr.downloader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;



public class DownloaderClass extends Activity {

    EditText txturl;
    int progress=0;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public DownloaderClass(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_download);

    }

    public void onDownload(View v){
        txturl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtURL);

        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(DownloaderClass.this);

        final AsyncDownloaderClass asyncDownloaderClass=new AsyncDownloaderClass();
        asyncDownloaderClass.execute("http://pinnest.net/newpinnest/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1377250577ea43d.jpg");
    }
    class AsyncDownloaderClass extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, String>
    {
        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
        Context context;
        String filename, basename;
        int fileLength;

        DownloaderClass downloaderClass;
        public AsyncDownloaderClass(){

            downloaderClass=new DownloaderClass();
            context=downloaderClass;

            /*PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,getClass().getName());*/
        }
        protected void onPreExecute(){
           // super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading....");
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            //progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
            //progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            new AsyncDownloaderClass().cancel(true);
                        }
                    }
            );


            //mWakeLock.acquire();
            progressDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           //return null;
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                Log.v("Do in background","calling.....");
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                    }

                input = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(input);

               fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                filename=url.getPath();
                filename=filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);



   output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"download.jpg");

               byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count=0;

               while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button

                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    Log.v("Error","Error");
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
            progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading... " + values[0] + "%");
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String... result){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.skr.downloader">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/download" android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name="com.example.skr.downloader.LauncherClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DownloaderClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="my.android.download"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `downloaderClass=new DownloaderClass();`. Remove that from your downloder class. Its nonsense.

Comment: `public void onDownload(View v)`. Who is calling that? And when? And why is it public?

Comment: `public DownloaderClass(){

    }`. Remove that. Why did you add that? You cannot instantiate an Activity with new.

Comment: @greenapps, i am new to android. onDownload(view v) is method mentioned in button onclick in layout xml file. I have removed DownloaderClass() constructor as you said. What else i want to do. Kindly help me.

Comment: `progress bar does not display any progress number`. Well then fileLength is 0. Did you check? What is the value of `total` when done?

Comment: `new AsyncDownloaderClass().cancel(true);`. It does not make sense to make a new one to cancel it directly.  Remove the context there too.

Comment: Please supply an url on the internet that we can try too.

Comment: I have verified by printing log. But pointer does not goest inside   while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) loop. I dont no why. also i doubt input.read(data) statement. Becuase at this stage data does not containg any values. I have tried for this url "http://pinnest.net/newpinnest/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1377250577ea43d.jpg".

Comment: Then change your post and put that url in it instead using that EditText txturl. Please klik the link and see that it does not deliver a .jpg as you added an extra space %20. Please remove or post a working url.

Comment: Partially i understood your comment. I have updated my post with that url. Now which link i want to click? and where i have added extra space?

Comment: You should add `e.printStackTrace();` in catch blocks.

Comment: Try the pinnest url you posted in that comment and see that it does not deliver a .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of onPostExecute is wrong. Change

```
protected void onPostExecute(String... result){
```

to

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String result){.
```

As now it is never called. And change

```
output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"download.jpg");
```

to

```
output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/download.jpg");
```

Comment: I have verified with this http://files2.filesrock.com/11/Kabali/Neruppu_Da-Tnwap.Net.mp3 link. and changed fileoutputstream, postexecute function. now, file downloaded toast is displayed. But file is not downloaded in my device. Can you please try with this new link. please add http:// before files2.

Comment: Why should i try with another url? The first url works here.

Comment: For me that ulr is not working. It throws exception "FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/download.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)". Even though i include permission in manifest file for both read and write in external storage location.

Comment: Then why do you think a different url would work? Please show your manifest file. Maybe you added the request for permissions wrong.

Comment: What else i want to change in my code to download file from given url. I am running this application on my mobile. My mobile having marshmallow version of android os.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with downloading or urls. You have a FileNotFoundException because you try to write to the file system. You could better just only open a FileOutPutStream until you have found the rigth way to do so.